# When something is cached in c# asp.net is it cached on the server or the client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, caching, singleton

```
 private Obj CacheSomething()
    {
       Obj retVal = (Obj)System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["key"];

        if (retVal == null)
        {
            retVal = new Obj();
            System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["key"] = retVal;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

This is probably a stupid question but is it stored in Server memory or client memory?

Also, what is the difference between doing the above and using a Singleton?

for example:

```
myObj= GenericSingleton<Obj>.GetInstance();
```

and

```
myObj= CacheSomething();
```

When I declare a new object every time it takes longer obviously, but both the above methods are faster than not caching and not using a singleton. Is using a singleton basically caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache` is server-side.
2. When using a `Singleton` pattern you usually write code expecting the singleton instance to exist. With cached item you can never rely on its existence and should write code accordingly. For example, if `retVal` creation is a time/resource consuming, you should `lock` to prevent other threads doing the same work of constructing it.

Comment: To be clear, when you say "threads", this means that each user would be using their own thread? So if I use this lock keyword, the resource that is being cached will only be cached once for all users (all users using the same resource)? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: HttpRequest's that come from different users are processed by different threads and this processing may happen at the same time. If the cached value is meant for everybody, it makes sense to let only one of these threads do the work of creating this cached object. Because the same code will be executed by every thread trying to access this object (and the cache key is the same for everybody in your code), yes, all users will use the same resource.

Comment: Apologies, these questions might seem obvious to you. One last question - if I had a locked singleton that I used to instantiate a class, the class would only get created once and each user would use that same object correct? So If the class were to generate different results based on user input, would all results be the same for each user? If the the app is supposed to behave differently for each thread/ user, the lock keyword should NOT be used. Is that right?

Comment: If you need to execute code with parameters that are user input, then I would use a static method rather than singleton/cached instance.

Answer (score 4):

It's cached on the server.  The most significant difference is that items can be evicted from the cache either because of memory pressure, or because you specified expiration or dependency information when inserting.

Answer (score 0):

It's cached on the server.
From the class manual:

> One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it remains valid as long as the application domain remains active. Information about an instance of this class is available through the Cache property of the HttpContext object or the Cache property of the Page object.

You can find it here: [Cache Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)